# Relational Algebra Query

Tags: database, relational-algebra

I'm stuck at the query below where i'll need to list out two attributes from different tables. Is there a simpler way to write the above query?

```
Tables:
Patient (PatientID, FamilyName, GivenName,Address) 
Item (ItemNo, Info, Fee)
Account (AccountNo, PatientID, Date)
AccountLine (AccountNo, ItemNo)
```

List the Item Info and the date of all treatments for any patient named John Wayne:

```
Select FamilyName =” Wayne” and GivenName=”John” (Patient)> Temp1
        Temp1*Temp1.PatientID = Account.PatientID (Account) > Temp2

 - Updated

Temp2*Temp2.AccountNo = AccountLine.AccountNo (Temp2 X Account) >Temp3
Temp3*Temp3.ItemNo = Item.ItemNo (Temp3x Item) > Temp4
Select Description, Date(Temp4)

Join Answer 
Select Description, Date (Restrict FamilyName =” Wayne” and GivenName=”John” (Patient) Join Account Join Item Join AccountLine)
```

Comment: That's a very unusual set of notations - you'll need to explain how it works (why does the first line have SELECT and the second not?).  You need to join all four tables; you are missing out AccountLine and Item at the moment.

Comment: I note this question have been edited numerous times. What you refer to as "Join Answer" looks to be simple enough and would give the correct results so it seems you've answered your own question. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks very much like `[homework]` so I'll just provide hints...

Rather than selecting from a table, you can select from a join
specifically, the natural join of `Patient` and `Account` table would, for one, allow finding all AccountNo and Date values that are associated with John Wayne.
Similarly another join would locate the Item Info given the AccountNo.
And since a join can be joined with another one (assuming there are no conflicts), seems like I almost solved it...

Comment: Ughh the orange bar of death ... I had DB Theory last fall and wanted to test my skills :)

Comment: Select FamilyName =” Wayne” and GivenName=”John” (Patient)> Temp1
Temp1*Temp1.PatientID = Account.PatientID (Account) > Temp2
Temp2*Temp2.AccountNo = AccountLine.AccountNo (Temp2 X Account) >Temp3
Temp3*Temp3.ItemNo = Item.ItemNo (Temp3x Item) > Temp4
Select Description, Date(Temp4)
In this way possible?

Comment: @user976050  I'm not familiar with the notation you are using.  Never the less you keep using intermediate variables whereby a `Selection` operation on a group of `natural joins` seems to be all that the "doctor has ordered".

Comment: @user976050: update your question rather than adding material in comments (without destroying the original question).  All else apart, you can get better formatting in a question than in a comment.

Comment: @mjv please advise if you meant in the way that i have updated.

Comment: @user976050:  no, you keep using temp1, temp2 variables, whereby the desired info can be obtained by a single Select against the "join" of all tables.

Comment: @user976050: Bingo. Again, I'm not familiar with the particular syntax you are using, but assuming that `join` means natural join (i.e. joining on the attributes that have the same name and value) and assuming that the syntax surrounding the use of `Restrict` is correct, this last snippet is what I had in mind.

Comment: @mjv That's the answer? So simple? I didn't thought of it. I always assume that only two tables can do natural join otherwise there would be conflicts.

Comment: @user976050: Note that natural join is associative AND commutative.